# Using an MXML component to set image through an array

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, components, mxml

I am trying to set a card image on the stage. The card suit and value is stored in an array and I need to use a component to set the image. Here is the part of the instructions that I am having trouble with:
 " In the function makeCard, use the suit and value inputs to construct the filename to use for this card's front face. Set the frontFile property to this filename. You might also want to set the backFile, which is the same for all the cards."

Here is the main MXML file code:

```
<fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            import spark.components.Image;

            public var suits:Array = ['clubs', 'diamond', 'heart', 'spade'];
            private var values:Array = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'jack', 'queen', 'king', 'ace'];

            private function init():void
            {
                for each (var suit:String in suits) {

                    for each (var value:String in values) {

                        var card:Card = new Card();
                        card.makeCard(suit, value);
                        card.turnDown();
                        card.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, flipCard);
                        playGrp.addElement(card);

                    }
                }
            }

            private function flipCard(e:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var card:Card = Card(e.currentTarget);
                card.turnOver();
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:TileGroup id="playGrp" requestedRowCount="4"
                 horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0"/>
```

Here is the component code I have so far:

```
<fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            //create variables for the front and back
            public var frontFile:String;
            public var backFile:String;

            //create function for making the car
            public function makeCard():void {

                frontFile = "asset/Cards_deck_" + + ".jpg";
                backFile =  "asset/Cards_back_" + + ".jpg";

            }

            //create function for turning the card over
            public function turnUp():void {

            }

            //create function for turning card over
            public function turnOver():void {

            }

            //create function for turning card down
            public function turnDown():void {

            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
```

edit: here are the directions 
What goes into the Card component?
For each card, we'll want to be able to show the front face of the card, or its back face. That means each card should have a place to store information about what file to show as its front face, and what file to show as its back face.

To do this, create two variables in the Card component to store the file names. You might call these variables frontFile and backFile.

Now let's think about the methods we need for our Card.
Take another look at the application file. Notice that the app assumes it can make calls to functions named

```
makeCard(), passing it Strings to specify the suit and the value for this card
turnUp()
turnOver()
```

That means you'll need to define public functions for each of these calls. While you're at it, go ahead and define a function named turnDown as well.

In the function makeCard, use the suit and value inputs to construct the filename to use for this card's front face. Set the frontFile property to this filename. You might also want to set the backFile, which is the same for all the cards.

In the function turnUp, just set the card's source property to whatever String is stored in its frontFile property.

In the function turnDown, set the card's source property to whatever String is stored in its backFile property.

In turnOver, you'll want to check to see which file is showing, and change the source to show the other side of the card.

Comment: I'm really not following what you're asking for help on.  It sounds like you want to change an image (the front of a card vs the back of a card); yet nowhere in your code do you have an Image class.

Comment: Please add your additional details to the question; as opposed to expanding on them in multiple comments.  Since you write the question, you should have an "Edit" Button.

Comment: Also, it is my understanding that the line " var card:Card = new Card();" will create a new "card" which is just an image I think.. The card component which is the second block of code makes that work.